# Pyinstaller > standalone Win .exe, creates dozens of files and folders: which ones to keep in distribution, and how to include my other .py files?

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller, kivymd

I'm creating a standalone Windows .exe with Pyinstaller.   Its created a lot of files and folders in its dist directory.
When I am distributing the .exe, I gather I have to distribute the DLLs and the PYD files, but what about the folders kivy, kivymd, certifi\ etc.?

**Also**, I have included in my main python file (called navdraw.py) a handful of my own modules I have written:  `MFile_Funcs.py, MString_Funcs.py, MColor_Functions.py`.  I don't want the user to be able to see these.
How do I include them in the standalone .exe ?   (I tried --add-data to each one but when I ran the .exe it still asked for those individual .py files to be present in the current dir before it would run.)

**Files created by Pyinstaller in dist**\

```
 <DIR>          altgraph-0.17.2.dist-info
         12,304 api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll
         11,576 api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-0.dll
         11,576 api-ms-win-core-debug-l1-1-0.dll
         11,576 api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-0.dll
         15,376 api-ms-win-core-file-l1-1-0.dll
         11,576 api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll
         11,792 api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll
         11,576 api-ms-win-core-handle-l1-1-0.dll
         12,088 api-ms-win-core-heap-l1-1-0.dll
         11,792 api-ms-win-core-interlocked-l1-1-0.dll
         12,600 api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-0.dll
         14,136 api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll
         12,088 api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-0.dll
         11,792 api-ms-win-core-namedpipe-l1-1-0.dll
         12,816 api-ms-win-core-processenvironment-l1-1-0.dll
         14,136 api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.dll
         12,304 api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll
         11,280 api-ms-win-core-profile-l1-1-0.dll
         12,304 api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-1-0.dll
         11,576 api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0.dll
         13,624 api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-1-0.dll
         12,088 api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll
         12,808 api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-1-0.dll
         12,088 api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll
         11,784 api-ms-win-core-util-l1-1-0.dll
         12,600 api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll
         15,672 api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll
         12,088 api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
         13,840 api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll
         12,600 api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
         12,088 api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
         21,008 api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
         19,768 api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll
         12,816 api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll
         16,400 api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
         17,960 api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
         18,472 api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
         14,136 api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
         12,296 api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
        800,520 base_library.zip
 <DIR>          build
 <DIR>          certifi
            173 color_theme.py
 <DIR>          dist
 <DIR>          docutils
          1,743 drivepath.py
          1,155 dropdown.py
        464,896 glew32.dll
 <DIR>          kivy
 <DIR>          kivymd
 <DIR>          kivy_install
      3,429,624 libcrypto-1_1.dll
         32,792 libffi-7.dll
        441,344 libFLAC-8.dll
        586,240 libfreetype-6.dll
        244,224 libjpeg-9.dll
        252,928 libmodplug-1.dll
        337,408 libmpg123-0.dll
         52,224 libogg-0.dll
        124,928 libopus-0.dll
         46,592 libopusfile-0.dll
        210,944 libpng16-16.dll
        695,032 libssl-1_1.dll
        432,640 libtiff-5.dll
        251,904 libvorbis-0.dll
         69,632 libvorbisfile-3.dll
        447,488 libwebp-7.dll
          1,656 LICENSE.FLAC.txt
          7,042 LICENSE.freetype.txt
          3,155 LICENSE.jpeg.txt
            193 LICENSE.modplug.txt
         41,624 LICENSE.mpg123.txt
          1,632 LICENSE.ogg-vorbis.txt
          2,107 LICENSE.opus.txt
          1,649 LICENSE.opusfile.txt
          5,611 LICENSE.png.txt
          1,301 LICENSE.tiff.txt
          1,660 LICENSE.webp.txt
          1,696 LICENSE.zlib.txt
            591 MColor_Functions.py
      6,065,952 mfc140u.dll
          3,053 MFile_Funcs.py
          4,353 MString_Funcs.py
        627,992 MSVCP140.dll
 <DIR>          PIL
        203,496 pyexpat.pyd
 <DIR>          pyinstaller-4.10.dist-info
      4,490,472 python39.dll
        556,544 pythoncom39.dll
        142,336 pywintypes39.dll
      1,471,488 SDL2.dll
        125,440 SDL2_image.dll
        123,904 SDL2_mixer.dll
         33,792 SDL2_ttf.dll
         28,904 select.pyd
      1,044,880 ucrtbase.dll
      1,121,512 unicodedata.pyd
         97,168 VCRUNTIME140.dll
        134,656 win32api.pyd
 <DIR>          win32com
        157,184 win32file.pyd
        228,864 win32gui.pyd
         22,528 win32trace.pyd
      1,428,480 win32ui.pyd
        108,544 zlib1.dll
         65,256 _asyncio.pyd
         86,760 _bz2.pyd
        126,696 _ctypes.pyd
        272,104 _decimal.pyd
        188,648 _elementtree.pyd
         66,280 _hashlib.pyd
        163,048 _lzma.pyd
         30,440 _multiprocessing.pyd
         46,312 _overlapped.pyd
         29,416 _queue.pyd
         80,104 _socket.pyd
        155,368 _ssl.pyd
         23,784 _uuid.pyd
         12,288 _win32sysloader.pyd
 <DIR>          __pycache__
```

**My current navdraw.spec file**:

```
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
block_cipher = None
a = Analysis(['navdraw.py'],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

a.datas += [('Code\navdraw.kv',
'C:\\kivymd\\exe\navdraw.kv', 'DATA')]  


exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts, 
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='navdraw',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
Tree('C:\\kivymd\\exe\\'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas, 
               *[Tree(p) for p in
               (sdl2.dep_bins +
               glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='navdraw')
```

**Pyinstaller command line I tried**:
`pyinstaller --add-data "MFile_Funcs.py;_Functions.py;." --add-data "MString_Funcs.py;." --add-data "drivepath.py;." navdraw.spec -y -F`

Answer (score 1):

By default, `Pyinstaller` creates a one folder distributable, and that is what your `spec` file does. Also when you specify a `spec` file on the `Pyinstaller` command line, most other command line options are ignored, from the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html):

> Only the following command-line options have an effect when building
> from a spec file:
>
> ```
> --upx-dir
>
> --distpath
>
> --workpath
>
> --noconfirm
>
> --ascii
>
> --clean
> ```

so your `--add-data` command line options will have no effect. You can build a single file executable by removing your `navdraw.spec` file and run:

```
pyi-makespec --onefile navdraw.py
```

Then you can edit `navdraw.spec` to add any missing files (any files referenced by an `import` should be included automatically). Then just run:

```
pyinstaller navdraw.spec
```

The resulting `exe` file in the `dist` folder should be a stand alone executable.

Comment: Thanks!  I built the .spec file with and added the Kivy sdl2,glew etc.  It built but didn't not include my own external modules ```drivepath.py```.   Here's navdraw.spec file where I added the .py files.   Am I adding them correctly ? ```a.datas += [('Code\\navdraw.kv',
'C:\\kivymd\\exe\\navdraw.kv', 'DATA'),('Code\\MFile_Funcs.py',
'C:\\kivymd\\exe\\MFile_Funcs.py', 'DATA'),('Code\\MString_Funcs.py',
'C:\\kivymd\\exe\\MString_Funcs.py', 'DATA'),('Code\\MColor_Functions.py',
'C:\\kivymd\\exe\\MColor_Functions.py', 'DATA'),('Code\\drivepath.py',
'C:\\kivymd\\exe\\drivepath.py', 'DATA')]```

Comment: Are you actually using `drivepath.py` in your app? Is it imported?

Comment: I am.  However, its imported into my ```navdraw.kv``` file, not in the main ```navdraw.py``` file.  How do I approach that?

Comment: Each element in a `datas` should have just two entries. The first is where the file is, and the second is where it should end up in your distributed code (this is typically a relative path). For example, if your `navdraw.kv` is in the same folder as your `'navdraw.py`, then its entry can be simply `('navdraw.kv', '.')`. See the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files).

Comment: Thanks.  During build process, now I am getting this ```stderr: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '.'
Cannot find ('C:\kivymd\exe\MColor_Functions.py', '.', 1, 'x')```  (Before build I delete the _pycache_ build and dist folders to make sure its a clean build.  I am running as admin. Any ideas why the error?

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to copy the innards of kivymd to protected folders. If you are using kivymd, you should just add it to the requirements in your spec file.

Comment: the kivymd/ folder is a folder I made.  The MFColor_Functions.py are modules that I have written.   Anyway, ... I do have write access in the '.' current folder.  I read somewhere that the a.datas[] line is not where I should be trying to include my .py files (.kv yes, but not .py).  Do you know where/how I can add my own .py files ?

Comment: Please have a look at the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files).  It describes the format of the `add_data` list, but it does not appear that you are following that format. What is the `import` statement that you are using in `kv` for the `MColor_Functions.py`?